# Convert diacritic or modifier diacritic Unicode character to 'combining form'

Tags: python, text, unicode

I have some accents/diacritics in a Unicode string that I want to convert into their 'combining form' (per the Unicode standard). For example, if I have `\N{CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT}` (`\u005E`) or `\N{MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT}` (`\u02C6`), I want to convert it to `\N{COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT}` (`\u0302`). Is there any consistent, reliable method for doing this for any diacritical mark? If the Python (3.9) standard library has in-built support for it (perhaps via the *unicodedata* module), that would be ideal, but I'm happy to use a pip package for this too.

Answer (score 2):

This is my current best solution. It feels a bit hacky still, but it seems to work in the scenarios I encounter.

```py
from typing import *
import unicodedata

def _strip_prefix(s: str, prefix: str) -> str:
    return s[len(prefix):] if s.startswith(prefix) else s

def make_combining_form(diacritic: str) -> Optional[str]:
    if unicodedata.category(diacritic) not in ("Sk", "Lm"):
        return None

    name = unicodedata.name(diacritic)
    name = _strip_prefix(name, "MODIFIER LETTER ")
    name = _strip_prefix(name, "COMBINING ")
    try:
        return unicodedata.lookup("COMBINING " + name)
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

Comment: Why return `None` instead of `diacritic`? I just tried this out by converting a string like `s = 'fe^te'` into `'fête'`, and if you return `diacritic`, it's as simple as `''.join(map(make_combining_form, s))`. Otherwise you need to loop manually, like `for c in s: fixed = make_combining_form(c); if fixed is None: ...`

Comment: This is more convenient for my particular use case, suffice to say. It’s trivial to modify though. The important logic is already there.

Comment: It’s not much more complicated: `''.join(make_combining_form(c) or c for c in s)`.